# duplicate image save to server in android

Tags: android

This is my Class Code:

```
imageView4 = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
imageView4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView4.getDrawingCache());
    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bm);

    // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
    File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));


    Future uploading = Ion.with(REFundPage.this)
            .load("http://192.168.1.103:9000/upload")
            .setMultipartFile("imagename", finalFile)
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result.getResult());

                        String digitalSignature = jobj.getString("message");


                        new RefundTask().execute(digitalSignature);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jobj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });


}
```

This is my Xml

```
 <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
            android:fadeEnabled="false"
            android:gestureColor="#000000"    
            android:gestureStrokeType="multiple" />
```

This is :

```
  public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

duplicate Image save to Server when i try to resend image to server please tell me where am doing mistake  first time i am able to send signature image but when i try to send second time same  image  save to server in android.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you can't send some image to server because it's already exist in server (duplicated) then you should proceed like this:

1- Your code should work but all you have to do is to generate a new file name for each images you upload.
 Or delete old one on server first.

Comment: We dont have to Delte actully we have to Keep all the file and also imagename different save but its same image save to server  its some msitake from CLient side but i am not finding where am doing mistake